# Como puedo incluir datos en una consulta que sean obligatorios

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Digamos que tengo estos datos

Documento1= 5555
Documento2= 7777

y esta consulta

```
select * from tabla where documento in(documento1,documento2)
```

como puedo hacer que la consulta incluya obligatoriamente los dos documentos

por que asi si uno de los dos esta se cumple  necesito que esten incluidos los dos obligatoriamente

Comment: Falta la estructura de la tabla, saber si documento es una llave única o si se puede repetir. Según la edición, entiendo que si solo está uno no debe regresar nada.

Comment: vos queres devolver varios registros si y solo si existen todoslos datos siempre? pone ejemplos claros

Answer (score 0):

```
(select campo,campoN from tabla
where documento = documento1)
union
(select campo,campoN from tabla
where documento = documento2)
```

Esta consulta usa el operador de conjunto union el cual concatena los elementos seleccionados de las dos consultas, la primera consulta se aplica para documento1 y la segunda para documento2, para usar este operador ambas consultas deben tener la misma cantidad de campos en el selectivo

Comment: Esta respuesta es solo una forma menos eficiente de hacer lo que ya hace la consulta en la pregunta y que además se dice que no es lo que se quiere.

Comment: @LuisCazares, entonces q quiere el usuario, no entiendo

Comment: Es lo que estamos esperando que aclare.